# Error 1064 Syntax Error MySQL Table Creation

Tags: mysql, windows-7

Creating a table in MySQL results in error 1064. I do not have restricted words for table name.

```
mysql> create database NamesInc
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> create table NameInfo(
   -> Name_ID NUMBER(8),
   -> Language VARCHAR2(10),
   -> Status VARCHAR2(10),
   -> Standard VARCHAR2(10),
   -> Place_ID Number(8) NOT NULL,
   -> Supplier_ID NUMBER(8) NOT NULL, 
   -> Date Supplied DATE,
   -> PRIMARY KEY (Name_ID),
   -> );
Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(8),
Language VARCHAR2(8),
Status VARCHAR2(10),
PL' at line 2
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Comment: use `INT` instead of `NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After create db statement do:

```
USE NamesInc;

create table NameInfo(
    Name_ID INT(8),
    Language VARCHAR(10),
    Status VARCHAR(10),
    Standard VARCHAR(10),
    Place_ID INT(8) NOT NULL,
    Supplier_ID INT(8) NOT NULL, 
    Date_Supplied DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (Name_ID)
    );
```